# AppCelerator Titanium + dalvikvm potential memory leak

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

I'm a newbie in mobile development using AppCelerator Titanium.

I have a `ScrollView` as parent where each `View` loads information each time a scroll event occurs but when I scroll several times, an error is thrown:

```
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa616d908)
[INFO] :   Process: Sending signal. PID: 6824 SIG: 9
```

Is this a memory leak?

Comment: Do you have more logcat information ? (put your log level in verbose)

Comment: There should be more in logcat!